# Can we define a parent Hamiltonian for a given Multiscale Entanglement Renormalization Ansatz (MERA) state?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, tensor-network

Given a state represented by a MERA (Multiscale Entanglement Renormalization Ansatz), can we define a local Hamiltonian such that the MERA is the exact ground state of such a Hamiltonian? If this is true, can we put any bounds on the locality of the Hamiltonian (e.g. 2-locality, nearest neighbour, etc.).

I can't seem to find anything in the literature. However, I'm somewhat new to the area so don't know where to look. Any references to the literature would be useful.

Comment: Please define acronyms at first use (in the title, and *especially* in the title) unless they are so common that there is very little chance they won't be understood.  QM for quantum mechanics is probably ok.  SUVAT for kinematic equations:  no.  Plenty of people have never heard of SUVAT.